# Testcafe Wait until an element has a specific text

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

After uploading an image with TestCafe the server will do some processing. While this time a label on the website will have "Inprogress" as a label. After the server is ready it will change to date. However, I want to tell the Testcafe script to wait until the label is not "Inporgress" anymore. 
For this I did:

```
    const DeliveryStatus = {
        element: Selector('div.cl-asset-published').with({timeout: 70000}),
        delivered: 'Inprogress'
    };
```

And in the script I have

```
await t
     .expect(DeliveryStatus.element).notContains(DeliveryStatus.delivered, { timeout: 70000 })
```

But this step fails. The message I got is "AssertionError: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but function given" but I do not have any idea why.

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass an element selector that returns the element but not a string to the `expect` function. Try using the element's `innerText` property instead as follows:

```
await t
 .expect(DeliveryStatus.element.innerText)
 .notContains(DeliveryStatus.delivered, { timeout: 70000 })
```